# CakePHP relations with different association keys

Tags: php, model, cakephp-1.3, relationship

I have two models `User` and `Post`. But the relation here is based on `username` in both tables. ie. `Post.username` and `User.username`

I am trying with following `hasMany` relation in user.php with cakephp 1.3

```
'Post' => array(
    'className' => 'Post',
    'dependent' => true,
    'foreignKey'   => 'username',
    'associatedKey'   => 'username'
),
```

But it's not creating relations between both models, when i am trying to fetch data using.

```
pr( $this->User->find('all') );
```

Here is the output even when posts are there for user 'vinni'

```
Array(
    [User] => Array(

        id => 2
        name => 'Vinay',
        username => 'vinni'

        [Post] => Array
        (

        )

    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct your models.

User **belongs to** Profile
Profile **has many** Users

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class User extends AppModel {

  $belongsTo = array(
    'Profile' => array(
      'className' => 'Profile',
      'foreignKey' => 'username'
    )
  );


<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Profile extends AppModel {

  $hasMany = array(
    'User' => array(
      'className' => 'User',
      'foreignKey' => 'username'
    )
  );
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working. I am getting related model as a key but without data.

Comment: I edit my answer. I put incorrect information (Group instead of Profile). So, try again please.